# How to prevent empty subelement list error in Ansible loop?

Tags: scripting, ansible, ansible-playbook

When I try to loop (with Ansible 2.6 loop) with subelements through all public keys of a list of users and encounter a user which has no public keys defined:

```
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ item.1.pub_key }}"
  loop: "{{ users | subelements('ssh_pub_keys') | default ([]) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

I'm getting the following error: `the key 'ssh_pub_keys' should point to a list, got None`

When I try to use skip_missing like this:

```
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ item.1.pub_key }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', users, 'ssh_pub_keys', {'skip_missing': True})}}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

I get this error: `'list object' has no attribute 'username'`

This could be the users list:

```
users:
  - username: usera
    ssh_pub_keys:
      - from: home
        pub_key: kdzadizajdiazjd
      - from: work
        pub_key: dzadadazdzadzad
  - username: userb
    ssh_pub_keys:
      - from: home
        pub_key: kdzadizajdiazjd
      - from: work
        pub_key: dzadadazdzadzad
  - username: userc
  - username: userd
    ssh_pub_keys:
      - from: home
        pub_key: kdzadizajdiazjd
      - from: work
        pub_key: dzadadazdzadzad
```

How can I make the loop with subelements to go to the next user without throwing an error when a user is encountered which has no `ssh_pub_keys` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Error: the key 'ssh_pub_keys' should point to a list, got None.**"*

A: You might want to use [lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) and set **'skip_missing': True**.

```yaml
    loop: "{{ lookup('subelements',
                      users,
                      'ssh_pub_keys',
                      {'skip_missing': True}) }}"
```

---

Q: *"**Error: 'list object' has no attribute 'username'**"*

A: The index is missing. Fix it.

```yaml
    label: "{{ item.0.username }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try 'loop: "{{lookup('subelements', users, 'ssh_pub_keys', {'skip_missing': True})}}"'
I get the error: 'list object' has no attribute 'username'

Comment: It seems like when I remove the loop control, your solution works. Feel free to add that to your answer.

Comment: I've added the answer.